# PayPal Permissions Service API and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I've already asked this here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11289701/how-to-make-connection-between-paypal-accounts , but I read about PayPal and some API and found, that I need user give me permission to perform transactions with bills : to pay him money.

I want to ask if anyone know some resource or something else, that could help to make this working in Rails, beacuse I can't get how to use this PayPal API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found gem - https://github.com/moshbit/paypal_permissions